# Apps Script Sidebar Reference Error When Using Include

Tags: google-apps-script, sidebar

I created a `Google Apps Script` add-on to display a sidebar on click:

```
function displayPage_() {
  getScriptProperties_()
  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('PAGE');
  var html = htmlTemplate.evaluate()
          .setTitle('Connector');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

This successfully loads the file `PAGE.html` as long as it is simple html. However, when I try to add `include` like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include("STYLESHEET"); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

It throws this error:

```
[17-02-09 08:55:50:239 MST] Execution failed: ReferenceError: "include" is not defined.
```

It doesn't matter what is in the `include` it always fails.

I have done this before and it worked. As far as I can tell, I have this set up just like the other project, but it doesn't work in this project. I assume that I forgot to enable something, but don't know how to tell what is missing because the transcript is vague.

What am I missing? Or, doing wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I got crazy too...
Found it in an example provided in Google Script Reference, what I didn't know was that *include()* is a user-defined function. Paste this code and it will work:

```
function include(File) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(File).getContent();
};
```

Let me know if I understood properly.